# PowerMockito.verifyPrivate always working independently of parameters

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

As the title states, I can call verifyPrivate but it always gives me success even if I pass the wrong parameters to it.

***Real example***

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyService.class})
public class MyServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
MyService service;

@Mock
OperationSivRepo operationSivRepo;

@Test
public void getNbInscriptions_should_call_getNbOperationsSiv_with_OPERATION_INSCRIPTION_GAGE() throws Exception {
    // GIVEN
    Role role = Role.ADMINISTRATEUR;
    String operator = "operator";
    SivDto sivDto = new SivDto();

    // WHEN
    service.getNbInscriptions(operator, role, sivDto);

    // THEN
    verifyPrivate(service).invoke("privateMethod", operator, Role.ADMINISTRATEUR, sivDto);
  }
}
```

Now this code will succeed, even if I do something like

```
// THEN
verifyPrivate(service).invoke("privateMethod", "other string", Role.USER, new SivDto());
```

Maybe I'm missing something but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly. Did you put a debug point in `privateMethod` and see how many times it is getting called? This would have given you some hint.
It is getting called two times. Once when you call

```
service.getNbInscriptions(operator, role, sivDto);
```

and once when you use

```
verifyPrivate(service).invoke("privateMethod", operator, Role.ADMINISTRATEUR, sivDto);
```

Second time since it is getting called with the arguments you passed to invoke method, the tests always succeed.

Use `Spy` instead of `Mock`
Instead of

```
@InjectMocks
MyService service;
```

Use

```
@Spy
MyService myservice = new MyService(operationSivRepo)
```

Wiht this, second invocation to the method is not made and arguments are verified properly.

Comment: My bad... Indeed it worked ;) ty!!! btw since I need to InjectMocks into the Service being tested I ended up by mixing the two annotations Spy and InjectMocks and now working as expected!!! Thank you so much